# android relative out image jumping over

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to create a comments area and I am trying to make a comment design , each comment contains of text + member icon + member name... I am trying to write it like this but the icon keeps appearing over the member name , any help is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMemberName" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtComment" 
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtMemberName"/>


   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtMemberName" >
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the layout you want - Do you want a horizontal layout or 2 lines with text & then image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` to arrange the fields. One `LinearLayout` will separate right to left (the username/image area from the comment area), and another inner `LinearLayout` to separate top to bottom (the username from the user image).

This is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMemberName" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"        
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtComment" 
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks this works with a little modification , the linear layout height changed it to wrap_content not match_parent , Thanks alot.

Comment: Sure. Try to a `RelativeLayout` as much as you can. You have no idea how many times I've seen people complain it doesn't work right...